# Adjugate matrix-Almost Inverase

Tags: linear-algebra

I Came across the following statement: "If the inverse of the original matrix exists, the adjoint is "almost" that inverse".
What does it mean?

Moreover, intuitivly, what does the property $adj(A)=det(A)*(A^{-1})$ mean?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "intuitively" here, but we can certainly find the inverse by calculating the adjoint and *dividing* it by the determinant.  So, the adjoint is certainly a *multiple* of the inverse.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Now, I think thaI know what they mean in "almost" that inverse.
If you have the $adj(A)$ all you need to do is to divide by $Det(A)$ and you get the inverse of $A$